# static versus shared libraries in small embedded systems using C without OS (assuming XIP)

Tags: embedded, shared-libraries, static-libraries

Does small embedded system without RTOS/OS uses dynamic/shared libraries. my understanding is that its very tough to use it and will be not productive.

If we are calling an API multiple times which is present in a static library. Does API code will be placed at every call location like macro expansion or code/text will be common for all  calls. I think code/text will be common.

If I have made a static library for a .c files which has multiple API's and I am statically linking it with main file and in main file only one API has been called so my question is does whole library is included in final .bin or only particular API code.

from above questions you can assume that I am missing fundamentals itself so can anyone please provide the related links to brush up these.

Regards  
[edit]

I have tried following things

addition.c module

```
`int addition(int a,int b)`  
`{`  
`int result;`  
`result = a + b;`  
`return result;`  
`}`

`size addition.o`   
23        0       0      23      17 addition.o
```

multiplication.c module

```
`int multiplication(int a, int b)`  
`{`  
`int result;`  
`result = a * b;`  
`return result;`  
`}`
`size multiplication.o`  
21        0       0      21      15 multiplication.o
```

created object file of both and put in archieve

```
ar cr libarith.a addition.o multiplication.o
```

then statically linked to my main application
example.c module

```
`#include "header.h"`  
`#include <stdio.h>`  
`1:int main()`  
`2:{`  
`3:int result;`  
`4:result = addition(1,2);`  
`5:printf("addition result is : %d\n",result);`  
`6:result = multiplication(3,2);`  
`7:printf("multiplication result is :  %d\n",result);`  
`8:return 0;`  
`9:}`

gcc -static example.c -L. -larith -o example  

size of example  
511141     1928    7052  520121   7efb9 example
```

commented line number 6 of example.c
and again linked
    gcc -static example.c -L. -larith -o example
    size of example
    511109     1928    7052  520089   7ef99 example
32 bytes of difference between above two
thats mean addition.o is not included in example

merged both modules addition.c and multiplication.c as addmult.c as below
    `int addition(int a,int b)`
    `{`
    `int result;`
    `result = a + b;`
    `return result;`
    `}`
    `int multiplication(int a, int b)`
    `{`
    `int result;`
    `result = a * b;`
    `return result;`
    `}`

created object file and put in archieve
before doing that i have deleted previous archieve
    ar cr libarith.a addmult.o
now commented line number 6 of example.c
    gcc -static example.c -L. -larith -o example
    size example
    511093     1928    7052  520073   7ef89 example
uncommented line nmber 6 of example.c
    size example
    511141     1928    7052  520121   7efb9 example

My question is in both cases if both functions are called final text size is same but if only one function is called then there is difference of 16
but multiplication.o size is 23 so definitly it has been not included but how we will justify 16.
If i am missing some fundamental itself ?

Comment: An embedded system without any operating system -but running on the "bare metal"- cannot even have shared libraries, because these need a dynamic linker and a file system which should be provided by *some* operating system

Comment: your operating system has printf? where are the disassemblies of these binaries, the answers are there, the sizes dont tell the story, esp if this is x86.

Comment: thanks I was not aware of this now I have checked with following command  <br/>   `objdump  --disassemble example > output.txt` and got my answers

Answer (score 5):

To dynamically load and link a library at runtime requires code to perform the load/link operation. That capability is normally part of an operating system.  Moreover in a system without mass-storage of some kind, dynamic linking would not have any benefits since the dynamically linked code would have to exist in memory in any case so may as well have been statically linked.

To answer the second part of your question, a static library is simply a collection of object files in an archive.  The linker will only extract and link the object code necessary to resolve symbols referenced in the executable as a whole.  Some smart linkers can discard unused functions from within an object file, but you should not rely on that.

So by linking a static library you are not including all the unused code in the library.  You can probably tell that by comparing the size of all your library files with the size of the executable binary - you will probably see that your executable is far smaller than the sum of the sizes of the libraries linked.  Also your linker will have an option to create a map file which will tell you exactly what code has been included, and if it has a cross-reference output facility, what code references or is referenced by what.

If you are building your own static libraries, or even your own non-library code, it will pay to ensure good granularity at the object file level.  For example if an object file contains two functions, one used and one unused, most linkers will have no choice but to include both, whereas if the functions are defined in separate compilation units (source files), then they will be in separate object files (even when collated into a library) and can be separately linked.

Comment: So from second paragraph what i got that not so smart linkers will include whole Object file, lets assume that i have provided four API's  in a .c file and compiled it as .o and archived it, so if I am including only one API from this object file then also all four API's code will included in final binary? So to avoid this can we make libraries more modular(separate unrelated API's in different object files), My doubt, Is there any tradeoffs between more modular and memory requirements (may be library header in final binary etc) or in other way can we go like one API one object file ?

Comment: @Dev:  The splitting of code across multiple compilation units makes no difference to memory usage.  header files generally contain declarative code only, so do not in themselves contribute to memory usage.  For example you can have a single header declaring symbols defined across multiple object files; the presence of an unused declaration does not increase code size.  You only pay for what you use.  Of course some library function may be implemented using others (either public or internal), so you will certainly find code linked that you may not have called directly.

Answer (score 2):

If you really have a embedded system without any operating system, then your hardware has essentially a fixed software, which you can change only by physical means (e.g. a soldering iron, or plugging something, etc...). In that case, that software runs on the "bare iron" and is doing somehow what an OS is providing (it is managing the physical resources and interacts directly with the I/O ports by appropriate machine instruction).

In particular, an embedded system without any OS cannot have any kind of dynamic libraries, because by definition these libraries need to be inside some files (on the embedded processor), and to have files you need an operating system.

<sup>The exact definition of what exactly is an operating system is debatable and fuzzy; I believe that providing a file system is one of the roles of most current OSes</sup>

Since shared libraries (or static libraries) are libraries sitting inside some files, you cannot have them without an OS. Something which provide files is by definition an operating system.

Perhaps you are using a cross-development chain to develop your embedded software. If you want to get something which runs on the bare metal, your chain has to ultimately give a single binary image which you can flash into a ROM, then solder or plug that ROM -or transfer somehow physically- in your embedded hardware (some tools enable you to flash an entire self contained processor).

I believe you might be confused, and you should read more about [operating systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), [kernels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28computing%29), the [linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel), [file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system), [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall), [RTOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTOS), [linkers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) & [loaders](http://www.iecc.com/linker/), [cross-compilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler), [microcontrollers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller), [shared libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_library), [dynamic linkers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) ....

As Clifford suggested in comments, you could have an embedded system with some file system and some dynamic linker; in my view that would make an embryonic operating system, but it is a debatable matter of definition.

Notice that making a dynamic linker might not be an easy task (you'll need to do [relocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computer_science%29)); you could either make a generic [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) dynamic loader, or you could restrict the form of the dynamically loaded modules, and perhaps use your specific [ld script](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Scripts.html) to generate them.

Comment: You don't need a soldering iron to change the software on an OS-less system, as ypu later point out - that is almost never done anymore.  On or off-chip memory can programmed either directly through JTAG or proprietary in-system programming (ISP) interface or indirectly through bootloader code either in mask ROM or programmed directly via ISP.  Moreover, it is possible to have a file system without an OS; at what point a collection of system libraries becomes and OS however is perhaps debatable, but I would suggest that it is more than merely a filesystem.

Comment: Corrected to "soldering or plugging"

Comment: Not even plugging.  Off chip flash memory can be programmed via boundary-scan techniques (JTAG) - and that is almost invariably how it is done in development and often in production.  Some surface mount technologies preclude both socketing and manual soldering.

Comment: MSDOS claimed to be an operating system, and it provided almost only a file system and some crude I/O primitives with the ability to start one single program at a time. It did not had any scheduler, and it was not a multi-tasked thing.

Comment: Well yes, as I said it is debatable.  MS-DOS also provided memory management, command line interface, and an executable loader.  If I deployed an embedded system with say [ELM FatFs](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) or [EFSL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/efsl/) for example, I don't believe that it could be deemed to have an *operating system* by that fact alone.

Comment: I am using CodeSourcery as a cross toolchain for cortex-M3.

Comment: Thanks You have provided enough links to go for one week :)

Answer (score 2):

You already have all the fundamentals you need.  Without an operating system, mass storage (disc, filesystem, etc) and mulitple/many different programs that can take advantage of the shared library it doesnt make any sense.  You dont save anything and it probably costs you a little more if you were to fake it enough to use a shared library in a fixed bare metal environment.

You mentioned having codesourcery, how do you learn these things?  You disassemble your binaries and see what the compiler did.  Does it link the entire gcc library because you used one divide?  Does it link the entire C library because you used one function (does it even work to try to link a C library function, many have system calls to an operating system which you have to resolve).  Start by using a simple divide in a very simple function (needs to be generic)

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
 return(a/b);
}
```

DO NOT call that function with fixed constants and do not call it from the same .c file, the best thing would be to simply add that function as is, and do nothing else with it just have it sit there.  You may hit problems even trying to compile it, once you do, disassemble and see what the compiler did with it, see if the entire gcc library was added or just the code for that one function.

You cant trust any old web page or resource as it may not be the same tools you are using and may be out dated, the compiler you are using right now is the one that matters, right now, no other.  And the answers are all right there in front of you.

No, they dont use dynamic libraries, the functions needed are linked in as needed.  The optimizer may choose to inline some code, but in general the code for each function is in one place and each call to it is a call, it is not like a macro, in general.  Again the optimizer may choose otherwise for performance reasons (small enough functions that dont consume too much memory and are small enough that the code required to make a function call is excessive compared to the function itself.  Also that function needs to be in the same optimization space, for gcc this is the same .c file, for llvm this could be any code in the project.

I have some examples, cortex-m and others, bare metal.  http://github.com/dwelch67 you may find some that may help answer your questions, examine for example that the compiler will implement a public function like the one above AND inline it when used.  If you declare the function as static, then the optimizer, if it inlines, doesnt need to implement the function in the binary.  if you make a call to a function like that in the same .c file, for example

```
c = fun(10,5);
```

there is a good chance that the optimizer if used, will replace that code with

```
c = 2;
```

and not perform the divide at all.

Comment: create a collection of simple functions like the one above, some in their own files/objects some combined in an object, and make a library out of that collection of objects, then link that library in with some simple code that calls some of those functions, see what happens, see what is linked in, etc.

Comment: I have added one example with original question can you please comment on it ?